# Node.js - Executing code out of a string safely

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently coding a MongoDB learning page which uses Node.js and Express in the backend. One possibilty for the frontend-users is: sending their own queries to the database and getting the results (or errors) back to the frontend. They should have find/insert/update/-access to the database.

The query will be transferred as a string. Pseudo-Code: Client --> `<input type='text'>`  --> JSON --> Node.js-Server --> Execution of query --> `res.send(error/result)`.

First Google- and Stackoverflow-seaches showed, that `eval()` is exactly what I need in this case. But it shows also, that `eval()` is very dangerous. I imagine something like
`var string = "var fs = require('fs'); fs.createReadStream(..., function(...){ res.send(...)};"`or worse. A clever hacker surely can guess that a MongoDB-Learning-Page is based on Node.js and can easily verify the used frameworks and database drivers.

What would you recommend to do? Is there a kind of sandboxing which just grants access to the database and the `res,req`-Objects?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to create an abstraction layer in code for the strings being sent and not use eval at all. Giving end users via the web browser (client) the ability to execute directly is inherently dangerous, one should never do it.

Instead, create a string parser using [javascript string functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) and [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Your application will receive the string being sent, and parse it for validity and safety, you can even do a real-time review of such a string on the client side and provide the end users hints or errors if they have a malformed string. One the parsing side you can then craft the appropriate actions to take.

In programming and databases this is referred to as scaffolding for CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete).  It may entail a little more work to create this abstraction layer but it is worth it in the gains for purposes of securing your database.  In a sense, you create your own sandbox because, in the end, the only database execution code that can be run is what you extend in your abstraction.

Here is a refactor of your psuedo-code in this method:

```
Pseudo-Code: Client --> <input type='text'> --> Node.js-Server -->
Sanitize & Parse String Data into a safely executable query --> 
Execution of query --> res.send(error/result).`
```

Comment: That string parser will need to parse javascript syntax. Luckily we already have such a parser: jslint. The jslint source code includes a neat, well-commented javascript parser. Basically it's javascript-in-javascript. Now you have access to parser code you can safely stub out the dangerous parts.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Obviously the learning page is *about* MongoDB and not backed by it. Nevertheless my first idea to restrict the access holds true anyway. But if the need is only to have a kind of "try-out" environment you could maybe use a client side MongoDB implementation like [minimongo](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo)

---

If you really want to send database queries, you could at least restrict the rights of the MongoDB user your express application is using. This could be thought of as kind of a sandbox - you could e.g. restrict the user to `READ` operations only (of course this is not what you want I guess).

What I would recommend is to analyze if you really need the power of a full fledged database query in the front end. If you e.g. only require CRUD using IDs on a collection you can get away with a simple RESTful Webservice and requests like:

`GET /{collection}/{id}`, ...

If the needs get more complex, your API will get more complex of course.

If you want to expose the various MongoDB capabilities you should check out implementations of the [MongoDB HTTP Interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/).

A NodeJS implementation is [Crest](https://github.com/cordazar/crest) which might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: From what I gather in the question is the OP is actually trying to simulate a MongoDB learning environment, so he wants the end user to actually craft complete queries rather than using an API.

Comment: Ah I see, the learning page is about MongoDB. Edited my answer.

Comment: minimongo - that's a great idea..  let them hack away at their own instance of a DB.